# Listing source dependencies

Tags: java, python, lisp

What is the degree of source code dependency that can be resolved by examining at the source code for the following programming languages -- Java, Python and Lisp.

For example, can I say for sure by looking at a collection of Python files that examining all the "import" statements in every file are the only dependencies (source dependencies)?

In Lisp, I'm aware of the (load "filename") command that allows including function defined in other files.

Comment: That is what my aim is. I have specified the languages for which I expect an answer and moreover, the question itself seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Firstly, I didn't say that this is a great SO question. Nor do I expect a "great" answer. I was just trying to understand how easily source code dependencies can be resolved. Naturally, different programming languages might have different ways.

Answer (score 1):

1. Even if you find an "import" statement of whatever kind it is not shure that the code will use it.
2. In Java you can import a name space, but also use the full qualified name of the class without any import statement

   javax.swing.JButton but = new javax.swing.JButton("MyButton");
3. And last but not least all of them supports some kind of symbolic programming. You may use a plain string to get code loaded or executed:

   Object x = Class.forName("javax.swing."+compName);
   return x.toString();

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to import in Python

eg

```
somemodule = __import__("somemodulename")
```

also the path can be altered at runtime, so for example

```
import os
```

might not import the `os` module you expect.

you can also include code via other means

```
execfile(...)
execfile(filename[, globals[, locals]])

Read and execute a Python script from a file.
The globals and locals are dictionaries, defaulting to the current
globals and locals.  If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

you can even include pieces of code stored in a database or downloaded from a url

so no you can't say for sure

Comment: Great answer gnibbler! Could you explain what you mean by "..might not import the os module you expect..."?

Comment: @user866098, If you look at `sys.path`, you will see that the python libs are usually right after the current directory. So if you have `os.py` in the current directory, it'll find that one instead of the python library. Since it's possible to modify `sys.path` you could even have more directories before the standard python library, and any one of those could have a file called `os.py`